# How can I transform web.config values?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config

I am trying to make different config files for different cases (debug,release, etc.) and I would like to change some settings for different builds.

```
<configuration>
<applicationSettings>
<Program1.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="CustomerId" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Custormer1-13256</value>
  </setting>
</Program1.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

How can I change the value inside the tag  to something else?

```
   ex. <value>Customer2-343242</value>
```

Comment: Can you explain little clearly?

Comment: in web.config I have the following code. In web.conf2.config I want to change the value to customer2. I know that attributes can be transformed via xdt, I wonder if we can apply this for values too.

Comment: I am looking for something like Erwin suggested.

Answer (score 16):

Add `xdt:Locator="Match(name)"` to [Erwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16144008/542251)

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<applicationSettings>
    <Program1.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="CustomerId" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace" 
                                                             xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
            <value>Customer2-343242</value>
        </setting>
    </Program1.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your config to look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Program1.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="CustomerId" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Custormer1-13256</value>
      </setting>
    </Program1.Properties.Settings>

  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

And make a transform like this:

```
<configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Program1.Properties.Settings xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <setting name="CustomerId" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Custormer1-13256</value>
      </setting>
    </Program1.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

So you aren't really "changing" the value inner text so much as having it choose the right value for each build configuration you create.

Comment: This works great if you want to replace everything in the section.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <applicationSettings>
        <Program1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="CustomerId" serializeAs="String" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" >
                <value xdt:Transform="Replace">Customer2-343242</value>
            </setting>
        </Program1.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Web config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx):

```
<setting name="CustomerId" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <value>Customer2-343242</value>
</setting>
```

Comment: I have tried to put xdt:Transform="Replace" in that tag, but doesn't change anything inside the value

Comment: Did you add the second config by right clicking the original one and choosing 'Add config transforms"?

Comment: Yes, I even tried it via this site  webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com, doesn't replace anything

Comment: Are all the parent nodes of <setting> also in your transformation config?

Comment: Is it possible to post the complete config and transform config?

Comment: Could you post the transform config?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the transform in the full path for your Web.Config XML

```
<applicationSettings>
  <Program1.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="CustomerId">
      <value xdt:Transform="Replace">Customer2-343242</value>
    </setting>
  </Program1.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Then test it using the Preview Transform menu option